# How to use deferred.when with eventlistner and eventhandler?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to use one Deferred.when statement which can return an object after the  completion of an eventhandler. My code looks like something below. Can someone guide me how to  make it work? I am using dojo 1.7.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/_base/xhr",
    "dojo/_base/json","dojo/_base/Deferred","dijit/registry","dojo/_base/connect",
    "dojo/query","dojo/on","dojo/dom-attr","dojo/dom","dojo/has","dojo/json","dojo/dom-style"],
    function(declare,lang,xhr,json,Deferred,registry,connect,$,on,attr,dom,has,json,domStyle)
    {

        declare("model.Item", [], 
        {
            deferred:null,
            item:null,
Load: function(){
               this.deferred = new Deferred();

               var overlay = registry.byId("readFromStore");
                   overlay.show();
                   Deferred.when(connect.connect(registry.byId("storeReadOK"),"onClick",this,this.loadFromStorage), (return (this.deferred)));
                  // I want modification for the above line.
                }

loadFromStorage:function()
                {
            // Do something here
               this.deferred.callback(this.item);

           }
     return model.Item;
        }
    );
```

I also tried this below code for the Load function but it is also not working.

```
    Load: function(){

     this.deferred = new Deferred();

              connect.connect(registry.byId("storeReadOK"),"onClick",this,this.loadFromStorage);
                var overlay = registry.byId("readFromStore");
                    overlay.show();
                        //  Deferred.when(connect.connect(registry.byId("storeReadOK"),"onClick",this,this.loadFromStorage),(overlay.hide()));

                return this.deferred;
     }
```

Comment: Hi Anil. Which of your calls are asynchronous in your example ? My understanding of the general usage of Deferred is that you create one, start an asynchronous task that will resolve the deferred when it's done, and return the deferred. What exactly are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: There are some severe syntax errors in your example, I'm not certain what your intent is either, or whether those errors are the source of your problems.

Comment: usually you return this.deferred.promise immediately, then when you are done to fire complete the deferred you run a this.deferred.resolve(true/false)

Comment: Yes,there are some syntax error as I have placed that line to tell what I want to do. Actually, what I want is that my Load function return any value only after the execution of the event and the associated event handler.

Comment: The returning value is local this.deferred which holds the data of items( through this.deferred.callback(this.item);) but it seems that my Load function is immediately trying to return value even before I click on the storeReadOK button which is placed on div readFromStore which is responsible to collect the value from Local storage and put those data in deferred.

Comment: Hi All, I am really not able to figure out what I need to do here... is there any way so that I can make the Load function to wait for the event and it's corresponding eventhandler to execute first before returning this.deferred object ... please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code is working fine and I was facing problem due to some other bug in my code which i have rectified and is working fine now. Thanks to all the people who tried to help me.

```
   Load: function(){

 this.deferred = new Deferred();

          connect.connect(registry.byId("storeReadOK"),"onClick",this,this.loadFromStorage);
            var overlay = registry.byId("readFromStore");
                overlay.show();
               return this.deferred;
 }
```